# VBA hide rows based on conditional formatting(search and if formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to hide rows that is not colored by conditional formatting with formula. Lets say, my formula is `=IF(ISBLANK(typehere),0,SEARCH(typehere,$E6&$F6&$G6&$H6&$I6&$J6&$K6&$L6&$M6&$N6&$O6&$P6&$Q6))` and if it found the answer it'll color it yellow, but I want the rest that is not colored yellow to be hidden automatically.
Like so :

From this:
[image: from this]

to this:
[image: to this]

Please if anyone could enlighten me with this problem because I am very less than newbie in this field. Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: Quick note: It's a little trickier than you mentioned, because you don't actually want to hide *rows*, but a range.  See your info on the right, "Jack // **search**"? If you hide the entire row a non-yellow block is on, then that will get hidden.  Or, is it okay to hide that too?

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you for your quick response! the ''jack//search'' cell will not be placed there, it will be placed lets say H1.. so when rows are hidden, the search cell will not be affected.. is this ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple AutoFilter can do the job. You can filter data by cell color. If you don't want to apply AutoFilter manually, you can record simple macro and bound it to `Worksheet_Change` or whatever.

Comment: I always forget that a Filter lets you do it by cell color. ...it's the only thing in Excel without VBA that works with color IIRC. Good thinking!